# Home directory does not exist JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

I'm trying to run jboos as 7.1 and when I run the standalone.bat I get this error.
I have configured everything as you can see here:

```
Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\

JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java

JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.se
rver.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.c
onfig=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

13:21:17,915 Informaci¾n [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS015849: Home directory does not exist: C:\j
boss-as-7.1.1.Final"
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:3
28)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:242)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

The bin/standalone.conf.bat is this one:

```
rem ### -*- batch file -*- ######################################################
rem #                                                                          ##
rem #  JBoss Bootstrap Script Configuration                                    ##
rem #                                                                          ##
rem #############################################################################

rem # $Id: run.conf.bat 88820 2009-05-13 15:25:44Z dimitris@jboss.org $

rem #
rem # This batch file is executed by run.bat to initialize the environment
rem # variables that run.bat uses. It is recommended to use this file to
rem # configure these variables, rather than modifying run.bat itself.
rem #

rem Uncomment the following line to disable manipulation of JAVA_OPTS (JVM parameters)
rem set PRESERVE_JAVA_OPTS=true

if not "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" (
    echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: %    JAVA_OPTS%"
goto JAVA_OPTS_SET
)

rem #
rem # Specify the JBoss Profiler configuration file to load.
rem #
rem # Default is to not load a JBoss Profiler configuration file.
rem #
rem set "PROFILER=%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\jboss-profiler.properties"

rem #
rem # Specify the location of the Java home directory (it is recommended that
rem # this always be set). If set, then "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" will be used as
rem # the Java VM executable; otherwise, "%JAVA%" will be used (see below).
rem #
rem set "JAVA_HOME=C:\opt\jdk1.6.0_23"

rem #
rem # Specify the exact Java VM executable to use - only used if JAVA_HOME is
rem # not set. Default is "java".
rem #
rem set "JAVA=C:\opt\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\java"

rem #
rem # Specify options to pass to the Java VM. Note, there are some additional
rem # options that are always passed by run.bat.
rem #

rem # JVM memory allocation pool parameters - modify as appropriate.
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"

rem # Reduce the RMI GCs to once per hour for Sun JVMs.
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 - Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

rem # Warn when resolving remote XML DTDs or schemas.
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true"

rem # Make Byteman classes visible in all module loaders
rem # This is necessary to inject Byteman rules into AS7 deployments
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

rem # Set the default configuration file to use if -c or --server-config are not used
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"

rem # Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging
rem set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

rem # Sample JPDA settings for shared memory debugging
rem set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,address=jboss,server=y,suspend=n"

rem # Use JBoss Modules lockless mode
rem set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.lockless=true"

:JAVA_OPTS_SET
```

Why?. Thanks so much. Regards

Comment: Show us your `bin/run.bat`.

Comment: I edit it and you have it here.

Comment: Ups, it's jboss7 not jboss4. In this case include `bin/standalone.conf.bat` instead of `bin/run.bat`. Sorry

Comment: I did it. You have it here.

Comment: @rzymek, have you seen anything?. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was about unistalling my jboss and reinstall it again,Once I have done this and I have checked all the environment variables, everything Works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Try set value JBOSS_HOME without slash.
Instead C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\ -> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.

Answer (score 8):

For windows : set correctly JBOSS_HOME (with / slash) and rerun cmd in order to environment variable get exported

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same error on windows with wildfly. In my case I accidently had environment variable %JBOSS_HOME% set with a trailing backslash "\".
Removing the backslash solved the problem.

Comment: It was working for me with a trailing backslash - until I restarted my computer! Removing it made it work again.

Answer (score 2):

Your `JBOSS_HOME` enviroment variable was not properly set. It needs to point to the directory of your jboss server.

If you are trying to call something in windows under the `C:\` directory in windows without administrator permissions there can be issues. Try to move jboss and the `jboss_home` variable away from `c:\`

Comment: My jboss is in this folder: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\, so my JBOSS_HOME is this: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\, no?. Regards

Comment: I have permissions for all kind of users. So this is no the problem, I think

Comment: I assume you are using Windows Vista or newer that means there is a special protection system that prevents applications without administrator permissions to access `c:\` directly. It doesn't matter that your user has these permissions but the application needs to be started with these.

Comment: Where do you suggest to put it on?.

Comment: create a directory like server or something just not plain `c:\`

Comment: This not work because I have done it and I have the same problema and I have changed the jboss_home variable

Comment: Did you also change the jboss_home variable?

Comment: Yes, I dit it, so I don't know

Answer (score 2):

I was just dealing with same issue and actually helped to set JBOSS_HOME **without** the end slash: `d:\Programy\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final`